# How to handle event for a specific control in ListView(Xamarin)

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have a Listview with a ViewCell, in this ViewCell there are 3 images and 3 labels. For handling the tap events I write a GestureRecognizers for each controls.

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True"
            SeparatorColor="White"
            ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected"
            ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="16,8,16,4">
                                <Image Source="{Binding IconImageSource}" HeightRequest="36" WidthRequest="36"/>
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="8,0,0,0" Spacing="0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding LocalizedText}" TextColor="White"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Value}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="Small"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <BoxView Color="WhiteSmoke" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Opacity="0,5" />
                            <RelativeLayout Padding="0,4,0,4" >
                                <Image Source="ic_ecu_eye"
                                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.25}"
                                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0, Constant=4}"
                                       />
                                <Label Text="{Binding ViewedCount}" 
                                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.25, Constant=20}" />
                                <Image Source="ic_ecu_favorite" 
                                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5}"
                                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0, Constant=4}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding FavoriteCount}" 
                                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5, Constant=20}" />
                                <Image Source="ic_ecu_comment"  
                                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.75}"
                                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0, Constant=4}">

                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"   NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
                                <Label Text="{Binding CommentsCount}" 
                                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.75, Constant=20}">
                                     <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers> 
                                </Label>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </StackLayout>


                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Code-behind

```
async private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    { 
        // want to get listview item
    }
```

ListView_ItemTapped is for handling the listview tap event

```
async private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    { // easily get the tapped item via e.Item   }
```

Unlike listview tapped event, TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped cannot easily get the tapped item which I needed to process some logic behind. 
So that's my question, how can I get the tapped item if I tap a control inside a Listview in the GestureRecognizer event methods like here

```
async private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    { 
        // TODO:
    }
```

Comment: If you would switch to `Command` you could use the `CommandParameter`

Comment: You must tapped directly to your image then. Or you can try button with image, can set `CommandParameter` as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can do it with an event, I think it would be better to do it with the `Command` property that is in the `TapGestureRecognizer`. I have created a sample project for you to demonstrate this. You can find it [here](https://github.com/jfversluis/ListTapGestureSample).

Drop the `Tapped` property and start using the `Command`, like this.

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TapCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ThaPage}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

You will notice that the `Command` needs some work. This is because the `BindingContext` of the `ListView` will be the item a cell is bound to. While you want the Command to be on the `BindingContext` of the page. Doing it like this will read the `Command` from the BindingContext of 'ThaPage'. Don't forget to give your page the `x:Name="ThaPage"` attribute. You can probably think of a better name.

Second, there is the `CommandParameter`. By inserting `{Binding .} here. You bind the actual object of the item bound to that`Cell` to it.

Now in the `BindingContext`, define a `Command` like this:

```
public Command TapCommand => new Command<Foo>((fooObject) => Tapped(fooObject));

private void Tapped(Foo fooObject)
{
    DisplayAlert("Tapped!", fooObject.Bar, "Gotcha");
}
```

Between the angle brackets you can specify what type of object you are expecting. You can leave it out. Then just an `object` will be passed and you need to do the casting.

Then in the method handling the `Command` you will have the tapped object available to you. The object in my case is `Foo`, just for this example.

Comment: Thank you.  When I runs the example, I got something like 'Command' property not found on 'xxx.ViewModel'. Should I declare  a BindableProperty for TapCommand?

Answer (score 0):

Gerald answer is THE answer.

BTW I think you can try with

```
async private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
    // want to get listview item
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Article", ((YourModel)this.BindingContext).YourField, "Ok");

}
```

I have tried creating the ViewCell with Code and it works. I don't know if you have problems creating ViewCell with XAML.

this is my ViewCell's full code

```
class ListViewTemplateGrid : ViewCell
{
    public ListViewTemplateGrid(){

        TapGestureRecognizer tgr = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tgr.Tapped += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

            try {

                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Article", ((ListViewModel)this.BindingContext).Description, "Ok");

            }
            catch(Exception ex){

                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Ok");
            }

        };

        Label labelDescription = new Label() {VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center};
        labelDescription.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Description");
        labelDescription.GestureRecognizers.Add(tgr);

        Label labelQty = new Label() { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
        labelQty.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Qty");

        Label labelOrdered = new Label() { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
        labelOrdered.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Ordered");

        // Add controls to the grid
        Grid grid = CreateGrid();
        grid.Children.Add(labelDescription, 0,1,0,1);
        grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 1, 2, 0, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(labelQty, 2, 3, 0, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(SeparatorV(), 3, 4, 0, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(labelOrdered, 4, 5, 0, 1);

        grid.Children.Add(SeparatorH(), 0, 5, 1, 2);

        this.View = grid;

    }
}
```